# Encoding scheme for large data sets

Tags: encoding

Assume there is a secure transport layer that securely transfer files, what if we want to transfer multiple files over this channel in one round? well it should be encoded into same file so when Bob receive that file is able to decode and see multiple files (e.g photo albums). i think ASN.1 is good for small data sets (e.g text certificates) but in large data sets such an encoding scheme can increase ciphertext size.

My question is what encoding rule you recommend for large data sets? it must be **secure** (audited well to be exploit free) and **efficient** (don't increase size in large scale)

Comment: is this homework or are you looking for free consulting?

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman. not homework, really need to know what is the best solution for joining multiple files into one. that scheme must be acceptable in small scale too (e.g text)

Answer (score 0):

[ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) is actually an efficient encoding. If you look at DER encoding of a long sequence of bytes (an `OCTET STRING`), you will see something like this:

```
04 [len] [the data bytes]
```

where `04` is a single byte value, and `len` is the length of the data expressed in a reasonably compact format. The data bytes then follow, as is. Overhead for a long stream of length *n* bytes is *2+ceil(log2(n)/8)* bytes; in other words, for a stream of up to, say, 256 terabytes, the overhead will be at most *eight bytes*.

One quirk of DER is that you have to know the total length of the data before beginning to encode it. However, the [BER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) encoding (of which DER is just a subset) can come to the rescue: a value can be split into successive chunks, without needing a prior notion of the number of chunks. Overhead per chunk will be minimal (say 4 bytes for chunks up to 64 kilobytes), allowing for a total overhead of less than 0.01%. You will have trouble doing better.

If you want to split that big stream into several internal "files" then you will need some convention, and, there again, ASN.1 is efficient:

```
BigStream ::= SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE {
        fileName    UTF8String,
        fileData    OCTET STRING
}
```

One general header for the `SEQUENCE OF` (less than 8 bytes); then, for each file, the overhead beyond the data itself and the name (an UTF-8 string) will be less than 20 bytes (usually substantially less) if you use DER. For huge files such that the length is not easily computable in advance, BER encoding can be used, with an overhead which can be lowered to 0.01%, as explained above.

If you are short on size, and the data is "normal data" (with some structure), consider applying [compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression). Most programming framework can use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) or already offer a zlib-compatible implementation (e.g. Java and C#/.NET both have it).

---

As for **audit**, this is not a matter of encoding but of *implementation*. ASN.1/BER encoding can be implemented in few lines of code, especially if you are interested only in `OCTET STRING`, `UTF8String` and `SEQUENCE`. We are talking about less than 1000 lines of commented Java or C# here; if you cannot audit *that* then you cannot audit anything.